# How to create class containing property of various types in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class to represent the value of a column in SQL. Here's the final goal I want to reach:

```
public string GenerateInsertSql()
{
  StringBuilder insertSql = new StringBuilder();
  insertSql.Append("INSERT INTO " + SchemaName + "." + TableName + "\n");
  insertSql.Append("(\n");
  int counter = 0;
  foreach (ColumnValue columnValue in _insertValues)
  {
    if (counter > 0) insertSql.Append(",");
    counter++;
    insertSql.Append(columnValue.ColumnName).Append("\n");
  }
  insertSql.Append(")\n");
  insertSql.Append("VALUES\n");
  insertSql.Append("(\n");
  counter = 0;
  foreach (ColumnValue columnValue in _insertValues)
  {
    if (counter > 0) insertSql.Append(",");
    counter++;
    insertSql.Append(columnValue.SqlValue).Append("\n");
  }
  insertSql.Append(")\n");
}
```

So the class is the `ColumnValue` class mentioned above. The `ColumnValue` class needs a `Value` property which can presumably be any basic .NET type (int, string etc). The class also has a property, `SqlValue`, which provides a string representation of the `Value` property which I can use in the generated SQL statement. So if `Value` is an int, then `SqlValue` just gives `Value.ToString()`, whereas if `Value` is a string, `SqlValue` needs to check if the string is null in order to either return 'NULL' or the `Value` property itself.

Initially I tried to have `Value` as an object and `SqlValue` to test the type of `Value` in a switch statement:

```
public string SqlValue
{
  get
  {
    switch (Value.GetType())
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

But then I get 'Value of integral type expected'. So I can't check an object's type.

Next I tried generics. I changed the `ColumnValue` class to `ColumnValue&lt;T&gt;`, with the `Value` property as follows:

```
public T Value { get; set; }
```

And then, in the `SqlValue` property, another check of the type of T, but I'm not allowed to do that either.

Is there a way to achieve this in C# without simply creating separate classes to handle each possible type of column?

Comment: Creating SQL via string concatenation? I'd be more worried about Sql Injection.

Comment: Thanks for the warning but this is just SQL generation by a test class. There is no user input involved whatsoever.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the SQL above could be quickly modified to parameterise values, thus protecting it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch keyword can take only integers (correctly speaking, integral type (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc9te331%28v=VS.90%29.aspx))). But you can always use "if" statements. For example,

```
var t = value.GetType();
if (t == typeof(string))
{
   ..
}
else if (t == typeof(int))
{
}
else if ...
```

You can also use "is" keyword. For example,

```
if (value is string) 
{
  ...
}
else if (value is int)
{
  ...
}
else if ...
```

"is" operator will also check within inheritance hierarchy but I don't think that will be the case in your usage.

Lastly, I hope that whatever SqlValue implementation that you are going to do will handle escaping (for example - quotes within string values) and will protect against sql injection attacks. You may consider generating parameterized query insetad (i.e. add parameter for each column in the query and then pass actual values as parameter values - so you won't need SqlValue property at all).

Comment: It's not true that switch only takes ints. Might be best to edit that one.

Comment: Regarding your final paragraph, it's the null checking for nullable types that is required here - that's the purpose of the SqlValue property.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your post. switch can indeed only accept 'integral types'. I had assumed it was the GetType() call that was failing, but it was in fact its use in a switch that was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: VinayC - Switch statement can only take constant values - this includes strings. It is not true (in c#) that switch can only take integral type.

Answer (score 0):

If you use parameters, you can have your SqlValue just return an object.

Your example will need to add quotes around strings and deal with culture issues (formatting of double, date).

Comment: And also testing for null... you're right about the quotes and date formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Type.GetTypeCode(Value.GetType()), which will turn it into the enum TypeCode which has all the primitive values retrieval from a database, especially enumerated. With the exception of Guid which will come up as object, but you can handle that in the object block.